# Magento: Add pagination and set column number

Tags: xml, magento

I am using magento 1.7,

To include pagination i am using the code,

```
<reference name="content">
  <block type="catalog/product_list" name="home" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
    <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>137</category_id></action>
      <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
        <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
      </block>
    <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
  </block>
</reference>
```

The above code is placed inside CMS > pages > design

This produces expected output, but i want to set "number of products" displayed ie, column_count as 5 along with pagination.How can i include column_count to above code?

I can make column count work by adding following code in CMS > pages > content,

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="5" category_id="2" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

But above code no pagination. How can i make both work at the same time.

Please help,

Thank u

Answer (score 1):

Add following code

```
<?php
    $_productCollection = clone $this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_productCollection->clear()
                   ->setPageSize(8)
                   ->load();      
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $this->setData('column_count',3);       
?>
```

under

> template/catalog/product/list.phtml

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer,

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="home" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
<action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>137</category_id></action>

<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
<block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
 </block>
<action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name><count>5</count></action>
</block>
 </reference>
```

Paste the above code in CMS > pages > design